# paypal and virtuemart: Order status is not changed after payment is made

Tags: joomla, paypal, virtuemart

I'm using Virtuemart 2.6.20. The payment method is paypal standard
When I place order, it redirects me to paypal gate. If I cancel the payment, it goes back to website and the order status is changed from pending to canceled. But when I make payment (completed), it doesn't go back to website and order status is not changed to "comfirmed"

Answer (score 0):

You would need to enable Auto-Return in your PayPal account, check this out for details: [Paypal settings for order auto-confirmation after payment (j2.5/vm2.x)](http://www.virtuemartrackingextension.com/virtuemart-tracking-extension-documentation/24-setup-paypal-to-auto-confirm-orders-in-virtuemart)